# Determining if one 2D vector is to the right or left of another

Tags: javascript, geometry

Given two 2D vectors, how can you tell whether the second is to the right (clockwise) of the first, or to the left (counter-clockwise)?

For instance, in these diagram B is to the right (counter-clockwise) of A

```
A   B   .       .----> A
^  ¬    |\      |   
| /     | \     |  
|/      V  \    V 
.       B   A   B
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can achieve this using a dot product. `dot(a, b) == a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y` can be used to find whether vectors are perpendicular:

```
var dot = a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y
if(dot > 0)
    console.log("<90 degrees")
else if(dot < 0)
    console.log(">90 degrees")
else
    console.log("90 degrees")
```

Put another way. `dot > 0` tells you if `a` is "in front of" `b`.

---

Assume `b` is on the right of `a`. Rotating `b` 90 degrees counterclockwise puts it in front of `a`.
Now assume `b` is on the left of `a`. Rotating `b` 90 degrees counterclockwise puts it behind `a`.

Therefore, the sign of `dot(a, rot90CCW(b))` tells you whether b is on the right or left of a, where `rot90CCW(b) == {x: -b.y, y: b.x}`.

Simplyifying:

```
var dot = a.x*-b.y + a.y*b.x;
if(dot > 0)
    console.log("b on the right of a")
else if(dot < 0)
    console.log("b on the left of a")
else
    console.log("b parallel/antiparallel to a")
```

Comment: I should point out that if you take your example with 'A' and 'B' as given and instead look at '-A' and '-B', so that each is pointing the opposite way, then -B is to the left of -A. But the dot product is the same, which means your code gives the opposite answer. The way you've defined the problem, your answer is more than just the sign of the dot product.

Comment: @eh9; no, B should still be on the right if you reverse both. I guess the question is "if A points forward, which side of it is b on"

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just using the cross product directly? You start with the dot product, but you finally end up with a cross product (or at least its norm).

Comment: While the formula is clear, the terminology is confusing. "The" dot product between the two given vectors A and B does not allow to answer the question correctly. You need to use the cross product A x B of A and B and look at  the sign of the z coordinate of A x B.

Comment: @J.T. This answer seems more accurate than the dot product one, lets say b points backward from A, but is still on the right side, dot product will not work correctly, compared to the cross product solution with the Z coordinate

Answer (score 1):

In the clarification in a comment from @Eric, *"if A points forward, which side of it is B on?"*

In this formulation the answer is dead-simple. "A" points forward, as in the example, when its x-coordinate is zero. With this assumption, "B" is on the right when its x-coordinate is positive, is on the left when negative, and is neither when zero.

Extending this clarification to "A" in general position means introducing a new coordinate system, as follows: *"In a coordinate system where A points forward, ..."*. The simplest new coordinate system is the one where the basis vectors are `A` and `(1,0)`.  (If A is a multiple of `(1,0)`, then it's just a 90 degree rotation of the basic situation.) The coordinate transform is `L : P = (P_x, P_y) --> P' = (P'_x, P'_y) = (A_y * P_x - A_x * P_y, P_y)`. This kind of linear transformation is called a skew transformation. The test is the sign of the coordinate `P'_x`. Check that L takes A to the vector (0,1) in the new coordinate system. This method uses the same arithmetic as the other answer.

I wrote this up so that the deeper geometric content may be illuminating.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product approach does not work if the vectors are orthogonal. For a general case you want to use the sign of the determinant of the matrix [A B], where A and B are your *column* vectors. A pseudo-code would be

c=sign(det([A B]))

Here, if c>0 is means that B is to the left. This will switch depending on the order of A and B in your matrix.

Comment: Note that the dot product approach is computing `dot(a, rot90CCW(b))` not `dot(a, b)`, so it does work when the vectors are orthogonal. But you're correct, another way to write this is `det([A, B])`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. +1

Answer (score -2):

@Eric there is a fundamental problem however with your dot product when the vector sizes vary greatly.

var dot = a.x*-b.y + a.y*b.x;

If a(2,-2) and b(-500,-500) clearly B is on the left of a, but doing the dot product it comes to greater than 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should consider putting this answer in a comment, as it is partly commentary. Otherwise, you should tidy it up and make it a fully usable answer.

Comment: No, b is on the right (clockwise) of a here, assuming a right-handed coordinate system